# How to copy a file and paste the full path to a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, java-7, absolute-path

Is it possible in Java to copy a file from the OS and paste it in a `JTextField` putting the full path of the copied file?

For example, i have the file "text.txt" on my desktop.

So i copy it with `RightClick -> Copy`

In the `JFrame` of my Java Application i focus into a `JTextField` and i use `CTRL+V`  to paste.Then the application should paste the full path of copied file into the `JTextField`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Java's Clipboard Class. Here is an Example

```
Clipboard sysClip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
 List<File> filesList= (List<File>)sysClip.getData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
          if(filesList!= null){
    Iterator<File> it = filesList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next().getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: @DevilingMaster check this out

Comment: It Works. Perfeect, Thanks. I can't use directly CTRL+V on the field focused but i can provide a button